# C++ OOP with class design

Tags: c++, oop

I have a task of calculating helicopter's necessary fuel intake. There are four operations a helicopter can do:

- Holding
- Raising
- Landing
- Straight

User selects the helicopter's actions by entering the parameters. I need to create this system with OOP approach. So far I have written the code as follows, but I think it doesn't have OOP properties.

Any ideas on how to make this system object-oriented? Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class helikopter {
    float result;

public:
    void    holding_flight(float time, float fuel);
    void    raising(float end, float start, float pace, float fuel);
    void    landing(float end, float start, float pace, float fuel);
    void    straight(float mesafe, float hiz, float yakit);
    void    calculate();
    //helikopter();
};

/*helikopter::helikopter(void){
    result=0;
}*/

void helikopter::holding_flight(float time, float fuel) {
    result += time * fuel * 60;
}

void helikopter::raising(float end, float start, float pace, float fuel){
    result += (end - start)/pace * fuel;
}

void helikopter::landing(float end, float start, float pace, float fuel) {
    result += (start - end)/pace * fuel;
}
void helikopter::straight(float mesafe, float hiz, float yakit) {
    result += mesafe/hiz * yakit;
}
void helikopter::calculate() {
    cout <<"Total required fuel : "<< result << "kg/second"<< endl;
}
int main(void) {
    float a, b;
    float c, d, e, f;
    char op;
    while(op != 'x') {
        helikopter h;
        cout << "Enter the move : " << endl;
        cout << "1 ---> Holding Flight" << endl;
        cout << "2 ---> Raising" << endl;
        cout << "3 ---> Landing " << endl;
        cout << "4 ---> Straight Flight " << endl;
        cout << "5 ---> Calculate fuel" << endl;
        cout << "x ---> Exit " << endl;

        op = std::getchar();

        if(op == '1') {
            cout << "Enter time : ";
            cin >> a; cout << "Enter fuel rate: ";
            cin >> b; h.holding_flight(a, b); }
        if(op == '2') {
            cout << "Enter ending altitude: ";
            cin >> c;
            cout << "Enter starting altitude: ";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Enter raising pace: ";
            cin >> e;
            cout << "Enter fuel rate: ";
            cin >> f;
            h.raising(c, d, e, f); }
        if(op == '3') {
            cout << "Enter ending altitude:  ";
            cin >> c;
            cout << "Enter starting altitude:  ";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Enter landing pace:  ";
            cin >> e;
            cout << "Enter fuel rate:  ";
            cin >> f; h.landing(c,d,e,f); }
        if(op == '4') {
            cout << "Enter ending altitude: ";
            cin >> a;
            cout << "Enter starting altitude: ";
            cin >> b;
            cout << "Enter fuel rate: ";
            cin >> c;
            h.straight(a, b, c); }
        if(op == '5') {
            h.calculate(); }
        if(op == 'x') {
            cout << "System will exit..." << endl; }
        else {
            //if(op==(1|2|3|4|5)){}
            //else cout << "Wrong selection." << endl;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I want to use most of the OOP principles, although it might seem unnecessary.

**SOLUTION:**

```
class FlyingMode {
   protected:
    float time, fuel_rate, start, end, pace, distance;
   public:
      FlyingMode(float a=0, float b=0, float c=0,
              float d=0, float e=0, float f=0){
         time = a;
         fuel_rate = b;
         start = c;
         end = d;
         pace = e;
         distance = f;
      }
      virtual int calcFuel(){
         return 0;
      }
};
class Holding: public FlyingMode{
   public:
      Holding(float a=0, float b=0, float c=0,
              float d=0, float e=0, float f=0):FlyingMode(a, b, c, d, e, f) { }

      int calcFuel(){
         return (time * fuel_rate * 60);
      }
};
class Raising: public FlyingMode{
   public:
      Raising(float a=0, float b=0, float c=0,
                  float d=0, float e=0, float f=0):FlyingMode(a, b, c, d, e, f) { }
      int calcFuel (){
          if(start < end && pace != 0 ){
              return ((end - start)/pace * fuel_rate);
          }else{
              return 0;
          }

      }
};
class Landing: public FlyingMode{
   public:
      Landing(float a=0, float b=0, float c=0,
                  float d=0, float e=0, float f=0):FlyingMode(a, b, c, d, e, f) { }
      int calcFuel (){
          if(start > end && pace != 0 ){
              return ((start - end)/pace * fuel_rate);
          }else{
              return 0;
          }
      }
};
class Straight: public FlyingMode{
   public:
      Straight(float a=0, float b=0, float c=0,
                  float d=0, float e=0, float f=0):FlyingMode(a, b, c, d, e, f) { }
      int calcFuel (){
          if(distance != 0 || pace != 0 ){
              return (distance/pace * fuel_rate);
          }else{
              return 0;
          }
      }
};
```

Comment: `I think it doesn't have OOP properties` Why do you think that? This is object-oriented code.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) on how to create a class, if you want a constructor etc.

You might also use the [new operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) to create your object it you like.

Comment: @petersv Why `new` actually? I'd recommend to avoid it like hell.

Comment: @petersv "You need a constructor" .. No you dont if you are fine with the default constructor. Even the example you are linking to has no custom constructor

Comment: @petersv I am repeating what was already said, but it cant be said often enough ;). Why new?? Imho this is about the worst advice you can give to a c++ beginner.

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf I would like to make the code more OOP. I was wondering if it is possible to add inheritance or abstraction to this code?

Comment: @supaplex Of course there is but is it needed?  Don't just add OOP features to make code more OOP.  make you code clear, concise and maintainable.

Comment: @supaplex The operations themselves would be good candidates to create a base class, and have a derived for each one. The helikopter class should aggregate them then.

Comment: @tobi303 sure, you are right, slightly misworded. I was more thinking in the sense that since this is an assignment, the assignment might specify that they want that. Anyway, I changed the wording a few minutes after my first comment.

Comment: @NathanOliver You are right, but this assignment will be evaluated according to its OOP properties.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hence, my initial hunch was correct. supaplex, you should change the question to describe what you want to achieve; to use the most "OO-features" possible, even when it's totally unnecessary and silly.

Comment: @supaplex using `new` when there is no need to, or providing an empty implementation of the default constructor is not OOP properties. IMHO this would rather demonstrate that OOP principles are overused and not well understood. OOP has its use for certain problems. Having a short and readable code is not a problem :P

Comment: This is object oriented enough for this example. It would be nice if you can post the answer if the instructor has other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a first view you did a lot of non OOP things in your example:

1) In main you are asking for data which is only related to the object you create later. The class should know which parameter it needs and not any unrelated method outside.

2) I can't see any real objects at all! What I can see is C code with the use of 'class' in front. The "object" you create has nothing it makes it a object.

So create a base class with a speaking name like: FlyingMode and one! method which is maybe called FuelConsuming. Make this method in the base class virtual and delete it!

Derive classes from this base class and overwrite FuelConsuming. The class names could be: Landing, Rising .... and so on.

Make your constructors of the classes interacting with the gui itself. Normally you should use a serializer, but at first make the cin/cout in the constructor. And for creating the instances of the mode classes you should read about a "factory".

This is only a very small hint to do OOP in your little example!

EDIT:
You should have a look at your code. Why you need 5 times the exact same code? Looks like a design problem! Give C++11 and inheriting constructors a chance.

The next is, that you have a object ( helicopter ) but you ask again and again for start altitude and so on. Model the real world: There is a helicopter object which flies. So collect your current state of the flight in the helicopter object.

You should read about design patterns in general.

Comment: I have added my solution to question with the help of your answer. Do you think the code has better OOP properties now?

Comment: so you think my solution in the edited question is still not OOP?

Comment: That is not a yes or no. And it is a discussion how the code solves your problem. But yes, you code is actually not OOP in most demains. But again: If you have no need to get the benefit of OOP or a more OOP like solution costs more time as you win, leave it as it is. OOP can help to get code reliable, maintainable, reusable. What from your main routine can be reused for other problems? How many lines you have to change if you get a new parameter? How many lines must be changed to add a new aircraft type? If any question results in "more than 5 lines" you have a point to think again :-)